# ¿Cómo insertar clave foránea tipo NULL?

Tags: php

El caso es que quiero insertar una clave foránea de tipo null el campo en la tabla es de tipo int, los datos enviados son de tipo array.

El resultado de este codigo es :

```
INSERT INTO familia_prove(idProveedor,idFamilia , familia_ids) 
VALUES ('46',' ', ' 1'),('46',' ', ' 2'),('46',' ', ' 12'),('46',' ', ' 13'),('46',' ', ' 14');
```

como se puede ver el for :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($idProveedor); $i++) {
            $idFamilias[$i] = null;
            $cadena .= "('" . $idProveedor[$i] . "',' " . $idFamilias[$i] . "', ' " . $idFamiliaSE[$i] . "'),";
```

me genera el query del insert y se puede ver que hay cadenas vacias que se esta inviando y no me permite insertar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$idFamilia   = $this->input->post('idFamilia');
$idProveedor = $this->input->post('idProveedor');
$idFamiliaSE = $this->input->post('idFamiliaSE');
if ($idFamilia === null) {
    $cadena = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($idProveedor); $i++) {
        $idFamilias[$i] = null;
        $cadena .= "('" . $idProveedor[$i] . "',' " . $idFamilias[$i] . "', ' " . $idFamiliaSE[$i] . "'),";
    }
    $cadena_final = substr($cadena, 0, -1);
    $cadena_final .= ";";
    $this->db->insert('proveedor', $data);
    $valor = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO familia_prove(idProveedor,idFamilia , familia_ids) VALUES $cadena_final");
    echo json_encode($valor);
    if ($valor = $this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es un poco confusa.  Puedes explicar que campo es la llave foranea?  Que es lo que pasa cuando corres tu codigo?  Algun error?

Comment: Podrías haber puesto el error, ya que has puesto un código que cuando se ejecuta no hace nada. ¿Podría ser que tienes en la base de datos en campo que es clave foránea NOT NULL y al hacer el INSERT falla?

Comment: Modifique mi pregunta haber si pudiera ayudarme por favor..

Comment: La llave foránea no hace nada por la nulidad del campo. Es el campo en la tabla referenciada el que se define como nulo o no nulo y la llave sólo valida que el valor que intentas insertar exista en la tabla referenciada.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu clave foránea es 1) tipo numérica y 2) permite nulos, el valor a insertar *no* debe ir entre comillas. Si el valor tiene un dato válido, irá el número correspondiente; si el valor no tiene dato, irá el valor null. Otra acotación es no confundir el null de PHP con el null de tu base de datos. Si lo notas, al pasar tu null PHP a cadena, llega un vacío. En su lugar, debes escribir textualmente la palabra NULL para que así quede expresada en la cadena final.

`// el valor nulo como cadena:`
`$idFamilias[$i] = "NULL";`

(Estoy en móvil, disculpen lo escueta de la respuesta).

Answer (score 0):

Especifica que Gestor de base de datos estas utilizando. 
Aunque independiente de alguno, coloca como nullable ese campo en el gestor.

Asumiento que estes usando MySQL, Marca la etiqueta como Nulo.
[image: Ejemplo]

Comment: el tipo de dato es INT y las casillas de predeterminado esta igualmente NULL de igual forma el checkbox tambien esta seleccionado

Comment: Veo que actualizaste tu pregunta, segun comentas te genera la siguiente expresion:
**INSERT INTO familia_prove(idProveedor,idFamilia , familia_ids) VALUES ('46',' ', ' 1'),('46',' ', ' 2'),('46',' ', ' 12'),('46',' ', ' 13'),('46',' ', ' 14');**
Sin embargo tendria que generarte algo como :
**INSERT INTO familia_prove(idProveedor,idFamilia , familia_ids) VALUES ('46',null, ' 1'),('46',null, ' 2'),('46',null, ' 12'),('46',null, ' 13'),('46',null, ' 14');** asumiento que la estructura de tu tabla permite nulos segun comentas.